# How to deploy API Gateway on Serverless 1.X?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

From Serverless 1.X, I can't found API Gateway settings in serverless.yml or web search results.
It include only lambda settings, and I deployed Hello World template to my AWS, actually only lambda was deployed.

How to deploy and configure API Gateway on Serverless 1.X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer of this by myself.

It is written in document here,

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/

and also, I was so careless, there are some sample of setting commented out in template.

This API Gateway setting is written like this:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
        path: hello
        method: get
```

So, API Gateway deploy setting is part of "functions=>events" setting.